# JS - open PDF in new Tab via XHR - with filename and auth header

Tags: javascript, rest, pdf, xmlhttprequest

Thank you for reading!

I want to open a PDF from a REST backend that gets loaded via XHR in a new tab with specified filename and Authorization header.

So far I managed to download it with this (incl. auth headers and filename):

```
// saves XHR stream as file with configurable filename
downloadXHRFile:function(endpoint,data,method,filename,errorcallback,mimetype){

   bsLoadingOverlayService.start();

   var def = $q.defer();

   var token = localStorageService.get('token');
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhr.open(method, CONFIG.URL+endpoint, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token);
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

   xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

   xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
         var blob=new Blob([this.response], {type:mimetype});
         var link=document.createElement('a');
         link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
         link.download=filename;
         link.click();
         bsLoadingOverlayService.stop();
      }else{
         bsLoadingOverlayService.stop();
         errorcallback(xhr.statusText);
      }
      def.resolve();
   };
   xhr.send(
      JSON.stringify(data)
   );

   return def;
},
```

Further I managed to open it in a new tab with the following code (incl. auth headers).
Unfortunately the URL (and by that the filename) looks like this:

blob:http://localhost:3000/0857f080-d152-48c6-b5fb-6e56292db651

Probably it can be solved somehow like above but I cant find the solution.
Does someone have a clever idea how I could set the filename in the new Tab?

```
// opens XHR filestream in tab
openXHRFile: function(endpoint,filename,errorcallback){

   var token = localStorageService.get('token');
   var our_url = CONFIG.URL+endpoint;

   var win = window.open('_blank');

   downloadFile(our_url, function(blob) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      win.location = url;
   });

   function downloadFile(url, success) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url, true);

      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer '+token);
      // xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (success) success(xhr.response);
         }else{

         }
      };
      xhr.send(null);
   }
},
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but not the time to solve it, any way, maybe it can be solved by opening an html page with embedded object: <object data="<url>" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="900px"></object>